# Linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Explain why 
>   $$\begin{bmatrix}
> 1 &a &0 &b &d &0\\
> 0 &0 &1 &c &e &0\\
> 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &1\\
> 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0\\
> 0 &0 &0 &0 &0 &0
> \end{bmatrix}$$
>   is linearly independent.

How can I tell if the rows of a matrix are linearly independent? Can I just take the transpose of it and check if every column has a pivot?

Comment: Generally including a zero row is not independent. Are you just looking at the first 3 rows?

Comment: Yes, just the first three rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linear independence is a notion generally used for a collection of vectors as opposed to a matrix.

The definition used by rg...d is correct albeit that there are five row vectors.  The last two are clearly not going to be helpful because they contribute zero to the sum in the definition regardless of the values of $\lambda_4,\lambda_5$.

In your specific example you can indeed immediately recognize that each of the first three vectors has a one in a column where all the other rows have zeroes and therefore has rank 3, i.e. three linearly independent rows (and indeed, necessarily also three linearly independent columns!).

Yes, you can transpose the matrix and do as you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition of linear independence (for 3 vectors): The only solution to 
 $$\lambda_1 \vec{v}_1 + \lambda_2 \vec{v}_2 + \lambda_3 \vec{v}_3 = 0$$
is $\lambda_1 = \lambda_2 = \lambda_3 = 0$.

Now consider what happens in your example. Your first vector $\langle 1, a, 0, b, d, 0\rangle$ is the only one with a nonzero first coordinate.

So what is the first coordinate of the expression:
 $$\lambda_1 \vec{v}_1 + \lambda_2 \vec{v}_2 + \lambda_3 \vec{v}_3$$
in your case? What does this imply about $\lambda_1$?

You can use the exact same reasoning for $\lambda_2$ now that you know what $\lambda_1$ is. Similarly with $\lambda_3$ now that you know $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.